# My code is not executing anything after the for loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having a problem with a test project in a visual studio. 
From my understanding, the problem comes from the function 'yeet'.
The function does not finish the loop, since it does not print out "why!!" .

Could someone help me in identifying what is wrong with my code?

Here is my code

---

```
string reet(char reet) {
    switch (reet) {
    case 'a':
        return "Zg";
        break;
    case'b':
        return "dA";
        break;
    case 'c':
        return "dG";
        break;
    case 'd':
        return "aw";
        break;
    case 'e':
        return "bw";
        break;
    case 'f':
        return "dQ";
        break;
    case 'g':
        return "cg";
        break;
    case 'h':
        return "ZA";
        break;
    case 'i':
        return "cQ";
        break;
    case 'j':
        return "YQ";
        break;
    case 'k':
        return "eA";
        break;
    case 'l':
        return "dw";
        break;
    case 'm':
        return "cw";
        break;
    case 'n':
        return "ag";
        break;
    case 'o':
        return "eQ";
        break;
    case 'p':
        return "bA";
        break;
    case 'q':
        return "aA";
        break;
    case 'r':
        return "ZQ";
        break;
    case 's':
        return "cA";
        break;
    case 't':
        return "aw";
        break;
    case 'u':
        return "eg";
        break;
    case 'v':
        return "bg";
        break;
    case 'w':
        return "aq";
        break;
    case 'x':
        return "bQ";
        break;
    case 'y':
        return "Yg";
        break;
    case 'z':
        return "Zw";
        break;
    }
}


void yeet(string input) {
    string yeet = input;
    string bigBoi = "";
    int yeetL = yeet.length() + 1;
    for (int x = 0; x < yeetL;) {
        bigBoi = bigBoi + reet(yeet[x]);
        x++;
        cout << bigBoi << endl;
    }
    cout << "why!" << endl;
}

int main() {
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    yeet(input);
}
```

---

For further Information, I am Using C++ on Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What input are you entering? `reet` does not return a value in all cases.

Comment: On the last iteration of the loop, you call `reet(yeet[yeet.length()])`. Here, `yeet[yeet.length()` is the character `\0` - the terminating NUL character. `reet('\0')` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of non-`void` function reaching the closing brace without encountering a `return` statement. In fact, depending on user input, it's possible you hit this case of undefined behavior sooner; but you definitely hit it on the last iteration regardless.

Comment: Which is why you should: 1. Use [`std::string::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) instead as it will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception. 2. Enable all compiler warnings which should tell you that not all paths return a value.

Comment: Ok, adding a default case worked. Thank you for helping!!

Comment: You can also consider `std::map<char, std::string> mp{{'a',"str1"},{'b',"str2"}}` -> `mp['a']` prints `"str1"`